# Pandas rolling over irregular time series with lowest deviation to regularly spaced series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I've got a DataFrame with a timestamp as an index, where the newest data has the highest frequency and the older the data is, the lower the frequency will be (to save memory).

Luckily pandas has the `rolling` module, which supports a time offset with for example `df.rolling('15T')` for 15 minutes rolling windows. But the deviations to rolling window applied to a time series interpolated to a regular time index are quite big. Especially the peaks are either flattened or too big.

**The code may look a little bit clunky, but most of it is just generating the sample data and plotting it.** The relevant about applying the rolling mean is only 4 lines of code.
The time stamp starts with 5-minute samples for the oldest samples, goes to 2-minute samples and finally to 1 minute samples for the newest data.
`df` is the irregularly spaced time series, `df2` is resampled and interpolated to 1-minute frequency and `df3` is resampled to 1-minute without interpolating. The DataFrames to which rolling means have been applied have an `r` appended to their names.
Standard deviations and norm are printed to compare the resulting deviations.
My example code to produce all different kinds of rolling means is the following.

```
tr1 = pd.date_range('20180820 1400', '20180820 1600', freq='1T')
tr2 = pd.date_range('20180820 1100', '20180820 1400', freq='2T')
tr3 = pd.date_range('20180820 0700', '20180820 1100', freq='5T')
tr = np.concatenate((tr3[:-1], tr2[:-1], tr1))
a = np.random.rand(tr.shape[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, index=tr, columns=['irreg. data'])
df2 = df.resample('1T').interpolate().rename(columns={'irreg. data': 'reg. data'})
df3 = df.asfreq('1T').rename(columns={'irreg. data': 'asfreq. data'})

freq = '15T'  # apply rolling mean with a window length of 15 minutes
dfr = df.rolling(freq).mean().rename(columns={'irreg. data': 'rolling irreg. data'})
df2r = df2.rolling(freq).mean().rename(columns={'reg. data': 'rolling reg. data'})
df3r = df3.rolling(freq).mean().rename(columns={'asfreq. data': 'rolling asfreq. data'})

fig = plt.figure()  # plot the comparison
ax1 = fig.gca()
df.plot.line(ax=ax1, marker='1')  # irregularly shaped time series
dfr.plot.line(ax=ax1, marker='o')  # roll. mean of irregularly shaped time series
df2.plot.line(ax=ax1)  # regularly shaped time series
df2r.plot.line(ax=ax1, marker='x')  # roll. mean of regularly shaped time series
df3.plot.line(ax=ax1)  # irreg. time series, resampled without interpolation
df3r.plot.line(ax=ax1, marker='4')  # roll. mean of irreg. time series, resampled without interpolation
ax1.legend()

dev_irreg = (dfr.resample('1T').interpolate().iloc[:, 0] - df2r.iloc[:, 0])
dev_asfreq = (df3r.resample('1T').interpolate().iloc[:, 0] - df2r.iloc[:, 0])
print('deviations irreg:', dev_irreg.std(axis=0), np.linalg.norm(dev_irreg))
print('deviations asfreq:', dev_asfreq.std(axis=0), np.linalg.norm(dev_asfreq))
```

---

### My question:

Is there any pandas module which will produce a result comparable to `df2r` (the dataframe which is interpolated to 1 minute before applying the rolling mean), without having to interpolate the data? Performance and especially memory usage is relevant, thus I'd like to avoid interpolating.
Furthermore the `asfreq` method in `df3` may have a slightly better deviance than using the irregularly spaced time series, but since I have to calculate differentials out of it, I don't really like the "plateaus".

Thanks for your help in advance!